# JPA with JTA transactions - get the JDBC connection

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, entitymanager, jta

This is my class:

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    UserTransaction tx;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void myMethod() throws Exception {
        try {
            // ...
            tx.begin();
            updateTable1();
            updateTable2();
            tx.commit();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void updateTable1() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Table1.updateQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    private void updateTable2() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Table2.updateQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

The JTA data source is defined in persistence.xml.

This is my understanding about this class: tx.begin() fetches a connection from connection pool. This connection will be used by entity manager in both updateTable1() and updateTable2(). tx.commit() returns the connection back to the connection pool after committing the changes to database. Am I correct?

Is it possible for me to get the JDBC connection used in the transaction in myMethod()?

Answer (score -2):

You can obtain the connection from the EntityManager as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager)

Comment: I am using JPA Hibernate. While trying this, I am getting the following exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface java.sql.Connection.